# Make Git "LF will be replaced by CRLF" warnings go away

Tags: git

I have setup Git so it doesn't commit inconsistent line endings. The problem with that is a whole pile of files appear modified even though they are not. What do I type to make these files have the line endings fixed on the local side?

```
# git checkout dev
M   src/au/policy/dao/EmailQueue.java
M   src/au/policy/dao/EmailQueueFactory.java
M   src/au/policy/dao/PolicyPublisher.java
Already on 'dev'

# git diff
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/au/policy/dao/EmailQueue.java
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/au/policy/dao/EmailQueueFactory.java
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/au/policy/dao/PolicyPublisher.java
```

This is what I added to my git config file which seems to do what I intended aside from this issue:

```
autocrlf = true
```

Comment: Would deleting the offending files and rechecking them out somehow be possible?

Comment: Yes, if there are no difference other than link endings just delete and re-check out the offending files.

Comment: Related, but not necessarily a duplicate question: [git replacing LF with CRLF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf).

Comment: "LF will be replaced by CRLF" warning happen when you are under Windows and your files contains "LF" (UNIX style 'new-lines').

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just delete and re-checkout the offending files from the index like this:

```
rm <files>
git checkout -- <files>
```

Or, if they are the only modified files (be careful with this command), you can script it like this:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M | xargs rm --
git checkout -- .
```

On a GNU system you can use a slightly safer pipe, but you don't appear to have spaces or other delimiting characters in your filenames in any case.

```
git diff -z --name-only --diff-filter=M | xargs -0 rm --
```

Comment: note to others finding this. see the answer in here regarding "git restore" command.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334475/git-how-to-update-checkout-a-single-file-from-remote-origin-master

Comment: Even tho this may work, this is not a suitable answer to work on a daily basis, I recommend using this configuration in your git config file: 
[core]
    autocrlf = input
    safecrlf = false

Answer (score 63):

This might happen if you change `core.autocrlf` config variable (if I understand your problem correctly).

If you are at **clean state, i.e. just after commit, and you don't have uncomitted changes**, forced re-checkout and removing index should do the trick:

> The below command `git reset --hard HEAD` will make your current branch to point to the latest commit and all uncommitted code will be lost. Make sure to commit the code or take the backup

```
$ rm .git/index
$ git reset --hard HEAD
```

That, I think, would sync both working area files, and the index (staging area) to follow crlf settings.

Comment: You obviously know your git, worked great for me. Thanks! Really! Thank you very much!

Comment: should consider this as an accepted answer. nicely worked @jakub

Answer (score 40):

I had this problem when creating new Xcode project.
My solution for this problem:

In terminal write

```
git config --global --edit
```

Then in git config file change *safecrlf* to *false*. My settings:

```
[core]
    autocrlf = input
    safecrlf = false
```

I know git have cmd line tools for this but they don't work for me.
And then Xcode create git repos without any problem.

Comment: @Andrei It's likely using [vim](http://www.vim.org/) as the editor, press escape to get out of input mode and type `:wq` to save and quit.

Comment: the only solution that worked for me, all the others failed, on "git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1" windows 7 (git bash)

Comment: i may be in the minority, but i would say nix the "$:" in your terminal command, it's just faster for copying and pasting.

Comment: only this thing helped me. thanks

Answer (score 26):

Only thing I can think of is to check if `core.safecrlf` is set to `warn`.

`git config --get core.safecrlf`

I *think* possible values are `true`, `false`, and `warn`. I believe that setting to `false` will resolve the warning, though it may not be a good idea.

Comment: This probably is just hiding the message but still retaining the effect of the cr/lf change.

Comment: Setting `safecrlf` to `false` can corrupt binary files, that's why it defaults to `warn`.

Comment: With many warning messages occurring, if any binary files are listed they are easily missed. Too many false positives. But then I don't have binary files in my repo. Still, it would be good to know which binary files git may treat as text files so as to understand the scope of the corruption in any future repo with binary files?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
cd src/au/policy/dao
dos2unix
```

If there are other files in that folder, then you'll want to break it up into the following (otherwise it will try to do it on every file in any subdirectories, which may take a while):

```
cd src/au/policy/dao
dos2unix EmailQueue.java
dos2unix EmailQueueFactory.java
dos2unix PolicyPublisher.java
```

It ran really quick on my machine and fixed all of the line endings, and it's a little simpler and easier than some of these other fixes.

Answer (score 2):

Note that note all of the above fixes may work for you, for example you might have received the code through a simple file transfer.
You can accept each warning by pressing ENTER, but on on large repos that can take ages.
Another way to ignore the conversion on code that has already been checked-out and edited is to create a patch file:

```
git diff > changes.patch
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after setting **autocrlf** variable to true, then running

```
git stash
```

and then

```
git stash pop
```

everything cleared out