# Git: How to update/checkout a single file from remote branch?

Tags: git, branch

I am trying to checkout a single file from a remote branch but am having trouble with the proper syntax. If this file was on master, I could run ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334475/git-how-to-update-checkout-a-single-file-from-remote-origin-master)):

```
$ git checkout origin/master -- path/to/file
```

but if I run a similar command with my branch name I get:

```
$ git checkout origin/my-branch-name -- path/to-file
fatal: invalid reference: origin/my-branch-name
```

What is the equivalent command to check out this single file on a remote branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the linked question `origin/master` is not a *remote* branch — it's **local** remote-tracking branch. If you don't have the branch locally you need to fetch it first:

```
git fetch origin
git branch -r # list local remote-tracking branches
git checkout origin/my-branch-name -- path/to-file
```