# Confused by GIT error message during commit

Tags: git

I am new to git and I am confused by this error message that keeps popping up when I commit:
*"warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in New Full Car.mdl.  The file will have its original line endings in your working directory."*

What does this mean?  How can I prevent it from showing me the error on a regular basis?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make CRLF warnings go away,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598260/make-crlf-warnings-go-away)

Comment: It might be a poor duplicate of that question.  I honestly didn't know enough when I was writing the question to know it was a Line feed error.  See my comment in the first answer to understand where I was coming from.

Comment: It wasn't meant personally.  Those sort of comments are merely to direct the attention of future viewers of this question, so that it acts as a "sign-post" of sorts.

Comment: No offense taking.  I appreciate you pointing out that thread as it helped me further understand the actual problem.  I was just further explaining the question with a little more hindsight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has to do with the `core.autocrlf` global config option.  See [this page on github](http://help.github.com/line-endings/) and check out [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510798/trying-to-fix-line-endings-with-git-filter-branch-but-having-no-luck/1511273#1511273) [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249932/git-1-6-4-beta-on-windows-msysgit-unix-or-dos-line-termination/1250133#1250133) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598260/make-crlf-warnings-go-away), and more.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up for me.  I use the abbreviation LF in my file a lot for Left Front (it's a car model and LF, RF, LR, RR are common abbreviations) so I was afraid it was replacing those.  I honestly didn't even think about the line feed connection.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like git is replacing your linefeeds (LF) with carriage-return line feeds (CRLF), so it's swapping the end line characters on the repository side while leaving them alone in your current working directory. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode) link for a description of newline characters.

If you want to avoid seeing that you could just change the newline characters in the `New Full Car.mdl` - it might do this when you pull from the repository, though if you've already pulled before it looks like it hasn't.