# Revert Xcode project without commit

Tags: ios, xcode, git, revert, git-revert

I might have wasted a lot of time. My commit wasn't working because of some warnings saying something about CLRF to LF.

I was looking for a fix and I did

```
$ rm .git/index
$ git reset --hard HEAD
```

Following [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598260/make-git-lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-warnings-go-away), it being in the morning, not fully comprehending what it said I executed the commands and my project reverted to my latest commit (which was a while ago because of the warnings I didn't try to fix as soon as I got them).

I got the Xcode alert saying the project changed and if I wanted to revert it or keep the Xcode version, I clicked to keep the Xcode version. As soon as I looked at my project I saw a lot of files were gone, not to be found in the trashcan.

I'm afraid to touch the project or do anything other answers suggest in case I mess it up even more.

It would be devastating if I can not get the files back, anyone got into a similar situation?

Comment: Was this uncommitted changes?

Comment: BTW - **commit early, commit often**. It's _**very difficult**_ to lose things it git once it's committed.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't commit in a while because of the warnings and thought I would just fix it later. I know that wasn't smart but never thought it would come to this

Comment: You can't recover uncommitted changes which have been reset. Unless you have another system dealing with snapshots/backups.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accidentally reverted to master, lost uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147680/accidentally-reverted-to-master-lost-uncommitted-changes)

Comment: Oh god please no, is there not a single place where the files go? Are they instantly permanently gone?

Comment: I am _really sorry_. I've been in your shoes and it sucks. This is the only time git can be horrible. Next time _always commit early_.

Comment: Dont you have Time Machine backups (or any kind of backups) ?

Comment: Time Machine isn't configured :/

Answer (score 0):

when git removes an untracked/uncommitted file it's permanently erased so git has nothing to do to recover the file

you can give a recovery tool a try it might help,
I'v used [EaseUS Mac data recovery](https://www.easeus.com/mac-file-recovery/) personally and it did recover a lot of my work after formatting disk accidentally.

hope it help you, I know that feeling